# Share a Spotify track using the Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, spotify

I've been using the Facebook API for quite a long time, I've managed to post to feed pictures, videos, and links, but **my client wants to post a Spotify track** through a Facebook App.

For instance, to share this track: http://open.spotify.com/track/5yEPxDjbbzUzyauGtnmVEC

When I copy this into Facebook's post input, it loads the correct song name and cover. However, if I use the `FB.ui` API call, it just doesn't share anything around.

```
var data = {
    method: 'feed',  
    link: MY_FB_TAB,
    name: name,
    caption: caption,
    description: description,
    message: '',
    picture: 'https://embed.spotify.com/oembed/?url=spotify:track:5yEPxDjbbzUzyauGtnmVEC',
    source: 'http://open.spotify.com/track/5yEPxDjbbzUzyauGtnmVEC'
}

FB.ui(data);
```

Isn't just a way to share a track using the `FB.ui` dialogs?

Comment: Try share just the URL. Let the other parameters be fetched by Facebook's scrapper.

Comment: Also the link should be the spotify link and not a link to your tab.

Comment: The problem is that the link should be the app's one, not the Spotify's one

Comment: Well that is the problem. You are shaing a link to your app and not to spotify. You can't have both :) It sounds like what you are trying to do is link-bait - Display content but clicking on it sends you to another location.

Comment: Yet you are able to share a youtube video together with the app's link

Comment: Ok @Lix, after checking a while and seeing nothing worked, post your comment as an answer and I'll accept you =) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks :) But I don't feel that I really answered anything. Feel free to add it yourself and accept though.